# mySQL echo row only once for each site in column

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code below:

```
$getSites = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getSites)) { 
if (!$row['site']==NULL){
echo $row["site"]."<a href='./php.php?site=".$row["site"]."'> (View logs)</a><br>";
}
}
```

Output:

test.com (View logs)

but I only want it to echo it once for each site name. So basically I don't want to have duplicates.

I'm sorry I do not really know how to ask this correctly but I tried :(

Answer (score 5):

Use instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT site FROM logs
```

Comment: You might want to order the results with `ORDER BY site` also.

Comment: Awesome! worked like a champ.. thanks for such a fast and understanding reply !